# Meaning of CPU Share and Compute characteristics for dyno types

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to understand the meaning of CPU Share and Compute for the different [dyno types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types) and I cannot find a clear explanation troughtout the documentation. For performance-m and performance-l dyno types there's not cpu sharing (you'd have 100% of the cpu resources), but what does de 1x or 2x mean?

On the other hand, for example, for standard-1x dyno you have 1x CPU Share and 1x-4x Compute. What's the meaning of this Compute range?

In an [old post](https://blog.heroku.com/2x-dynos-beta) in Heroku blog (from 2013), I've read about 2x dynos as something that doubles some basic 1x type. But I can't found more detailed information about this.

Comment: I think it's most helpful to think of dynos relative to other dynos rather than in absolute terms. From that perspective Heroku's documentation makes more sense. What is the context for your question? Are you trying to budget your monthly cost?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out a "dyno scheme" or architecture that would allow me to run my application and create some future scenarios for when it starts to scale. Just trying to understand concepts. From that relative terms points of view, what would be the meaning of the Computer range e.g. 1x-4x?

Comment: I also have this question - does 1x CPU on a 4CPU machine mean you are throttled at 1 CPU?